# Hide content of page in IE until scripts are totally loaded in jquery

Tags: jquery, cufon, jquery-cycle

IE harshing my mellow...

I don't want the jquery-controlled content of my page to display until jquery displays it. But in Internet Explorer, 7 and 8, the content blinks into view before jquery takes it over.  I've  tried $(window).load and $(document).ready functions, but I still have the same problem.

Specifically, I don't want my text to appear until Cufon displays it and I don't want my page #field to display until curvey corners has rounded off the corners. Also, I have   jquery cycle slideshows and all of the content of the slideshows displays all at once briefly.

One solution, but I'm not particularly keen on it, is to have the whole darn page fade in really fast with:

```
$(window).load(function(){$("#field").fadeIn(0);});
```

Even though the time is set to 0ms, this still works to make all the hidden content stay hidden until jquery displays it. But the down side is is that it makes the pages blink when navigating between them. (I'm playing with the duration, but with IE, it just makes the pages be blank longer--I have never, ever, been able to get anything to fade in in IE with jquery).

Here's the most involved page:http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/index.html
About and the main (home) index page in the top directory are up and running, I'm still working on the other stuff... Thanks!

Comment: Set a `body { display: none }` in your main css, then have jquery do `{display: block}` in the onload handler?

Comment: No ones provided a satisfactory answer, just variations on what I'm already doing... @Marc, your solution might be best, might be more elegant than the fade-in I'm doing now. Suggest it as an answer and if I test it and it works, I'll green check it unless someone has a better idea in the meantime...

Comment: +1 for "IE harshing my mellow..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marc B deserves the credit for this; I waited for three days so he could post his own version of the answer so I could green-check him.

Here's the final and tested code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("THE DIV CONTAINING MY PAGE").css('display', 'block');
 });
</script>
```

Very simple and effective.

Comment: Don't forget to add display:none to the CSS for THE DIV CONTAINING MY PAGE.

Comment: I bet this would work with Hussein's HTML display:none trick too.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. This is the same concept as what i provided below.

Answer (score 1):

One technique you could utilize would be to add the following in the <head> of your document.

```
<script>
document.documentElement.className = "js";
</script>
```

Then you could use CSS to make sure the elements are definitively hidden before showing them with JavaScript

```
.js .some-element {display: none;}
```

This also degrades gracefully if JavaScript for some reason does not work.

Comment: Wow--that's really elegant--I'll give that a try.

Comment: did I set that up correctly? http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/about/index-alt-01.html

Comment: You've got the JavaScript added twice, other than that, it's working, just make sure your CSS selectors are correct.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, still not working on my end... The underlying font still blinks into view before Cufon takes over...

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en" class="hideshow">
```

or

```
<html lang="en" style="display:none">
```

set it to display none, either inline style"display:none" or in your css file

You have jquery in your question tags, so i assume you are using jquery. If so, you can put this in your document ready function

```
$(function(){
$('.hideshow').fadeIn("slow").show();
});
```

or for the second one use.

```
$(function(){
$('html').fadeIn("slow").show();
});
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/NtCKn/

Comment: It doesn't matter, As long as all your calls are done within the read function $(function(){...}). For cufon just put the Cufon.replace('h1') inside the ready function. That way all fonts h1 tags render before page loads, .You would do the same with the corner plugin

Comment: I think you've got a pretty cool trick there, but it makes my background color fade in too which I'm not too keen on. Basically, it's the same fix as what I'm currently using mentioned in my question but mine is isolated to a  particular div not the entire page... I might be able to use your trick elsewhere so I'm up-voting your rep, but as a solution to my problem, it's a lateral move... But thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to style the elements in question with display:none; or visibility:hidden; with CSS, and then when the page loads use jQuery to show those elements?

Comment: Sure, that's the usual drill with getting stuff to fade in and out with jquery and it works with every browser I've tried it on but IE...

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    body {
     display: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

and onload, remove this through script:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){$('body').css('display:block');});
</script>
```

---

If you want functionality when browser is IE and JS is off (progressive enhancement is Good), the first code block will get slightly more complex:

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    body {
     display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style>
     body {
       display: block !important;
     }
    </style>
  </noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

This will hide the body, but only when JS is on (as the second `style` block will override the first in case JS is off).

Comment: Hmmm... Did I implement that correctly @Piskvor? http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/about/index-alt.html

Comment: @ian_6500: hmm, no, I don't think so: the `<!--[if IE]>` needs to be a complete block, same with `<![endif]-->`. If you're using normal HTML comments, those need to be separate from the conditional comments, although their syntax is similar. Note that I also made a typo in my post - should have been `<!--[if IE]>` - I was missing the closing `>`; sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: @Piskvor: Thanks! It does seem to detect IE, but now nothing shows up at all in IE, other browsers work... Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ian_6500: I missed the closing `);` in the JS part; maybe that was throwing an error (fixed in my post now)? Also, you seeem to have an `onload=preloadImages()` there, but no `function preloadImages`.

Comment: @ Piskvor Hmmm... still no joy, but it does show up in IE now, but the same original problem persists... Can you please check my code again?

Answer (score 0):

Settings CSS style display: none; to the Body or your wrapper element works well. Keep in mind, that some things don't always render well when hidden with display: none; In those cases you might need to use visibility: hidden; and then bring the element back to sight with visibility: visible; fadeIn() won't work for that, but a workaround is to .hide() -> visibility: visible and then .fadeIn() after document ready :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm just doing what I've been doing, what I mentioned in my question, just have the page fade in with jQuery which gives IE a fraction of a second to get its act together before displaying my Javascript-driven stuff. I've been using:

```
$(window).load(function(){$("THE DIV CONTAINING MY PAGE").fadeIn(0);});
```

...and will continue to do so. @alex provided a solution in his answer having all of the html fade in. That might work too, (I haven't tested it on the page in question specifically, but I still prefer my more localized fade-in as his method makes everything fade in, including the background color. I could see that being really cool on another site, but that look isn't quite right for me on this site...)

@Marc B suggested a very elegant solution in a comment under my question. I've invited him to restate it as an answer and if it works (and no one provides a better idea in the meantime,) I'll green-check him. (I'm thinking it'll work--I'll try it out next time I'm in front of my windows machine...)

If anyone else has any other ideas, I'd love to see them!